# Node js: fs WriteFile writing data to file twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fs, writefile

The fs.writeFile code in the backend is running twice.
The data appending appears in console twice and data is written twice in JSON file.

Any idea why this happens?
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: this seems like a front-end problem. onFavSubmit is running twice...

Front-end

```
    constructor (props) {
        super (props) 
            this.state = {
                inputOne: '',
                chosenOne: ['Favourite Movie', 'X'],
                chosenTwo: ['2nd Favourite Movie', 'X'],
                chosenThree: ['3rd Favourite Movie', 'X'],
                movies:[],
            };
            this.onFavSubmit = this.onFavSubmit.bind(this);
            this.onReset = this.onReset.bind(this);
    }
```

```
    onFavSubmit = event => {
        const newFav = {
            first: this.state.chosenOne[0],
            second: this.state.chosenTwo[0],
            third: this.state.chosenThree[0]
        }

        if(this.state.chosenOne[1] === 'X' || this.state.chosenTwo[1] === 'X' || this.state.chosenThree[1] === 'X'){
            alert ('Need All 3 Favourite Shows')
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            axios.post('http://localhost:8001/fav', {newFav})
            .then(
                alert('Successfully Added'),
                this.onReset()
            )
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response))
        }
    }
```

```
<button className="fav__button" type="button" onClick={this.onFavSubmit}>Click Me</button>
```

Back-end

```
const express = require("express");
const favData = require("../data/fav.json")
const fs = require ('fs')
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (_, res) => {
    res.json(favData);
  });

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const newFirst = req.body.newFav.first;
    const newSecond = req.body.newFav.second;
    const newThird = req.body.newFav.third;

    const newfavData = {
        First: newFirst,
        Second: newSecond,
        Third: newThird,
    };

    fs.readFile('./data/fav.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data){
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        json.push(newfavData);
        console.log(newfavData)
        fs.writeFile('./data/fav.json', JSON.stringify(json), function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('data appended')
            return;
        })
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: please provide context, what code is calling this piece of code?

Comment: I included the rest of my code

Comment: Are there also 2 requests, or only the function on backend fires twice?

Comment: I'm guessing the browser might try to prefetch website or something so the request at endpoint "/" is fired twice, same goes with fs.readFile - consider moving reading file on separate endpoint.

Comment: @Zydnar if I understand your question correctly, I changed to axios.post('http://localhost:8001/fav/fav', {newFav}) and router.post("/fav", (req, res) => {...} in the backend and still triggering twice...

Comment: You have to track the problem from beginning - what first is triggered twice - start at the beginning from click event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation so I can't comment. 
Have you tried commenting out `this.onReset()` and see if that fixes the problem?

There had been times when I was sending a request to "/" on reload.

Comment: Same problem sadly

Comment: You're probably firing the event twice, maybe you can include the code where you attached `onFavSubmit` to something.

Comment: I think you are right. onFavSubmit is running twice. Don't know what I did wrong though

Comment: Maybe you forgot to use `event.preventDefault()` in your `else` statement where `axios.post(...)` is invoked?